# React Native Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> /home/mahesh/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c0fe0d468b2d9842e23d5a9c1c80a565/res/values/values.xml:731:5-756:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
compileSdkVersion = 29
Thanks in advance

Android Gradle Plugin version 3.4.2

Comment: 1) cd android
2) ./gradlew clean
3) cd..
Enter these commands and try again

Comment: not working , using Android Gradle Plugin version 3.4.2 can please tell me for version 3.4.2 which buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion should be used

Comment: You can use higher build tool version than compile SDK version. You are using it.
If you are using @react-native-community/netinfo library, just update it. Error - resource android:attr/lStar not found seems to be related with that library.

Answer (score 0):

As @akshay said,

If you are using @react-native-community/netinfo library, update it.

This solved the problem